# Sharing files between jenkins master and slave nodes

Tags: powershell, jenkins

```
# test.ps1

function foo {
  echo "bar"
}
```

I have a file named `test.ps1` which contains some frequently called functions. And I want it to be shared between my jenkins master and slave nodes.

I've tried creating 2 copies of `test.ps1` and put them in master and slave nodes. But this is not convenient. Because I'll have to maintain 2 `test.ps1`s

Another way I've tried is putting 1 `test.ps1` at master node and copying `test.ps1` from master to slave with [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) whenever I need to use `test.ps1` at slave node. This is not convenient, either.

How can I share `test.ps1` between master and slave nodes?

Comment: are you using Linux or windows? how about creating a shared drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) solves my problem:

First, create a custom file using this plugin:

[image]

[image]

Write the name and content of this shared file. Then save it.
[image]

Inside your project, check `Provide Configuration files`
[image]
Jenkins will create `test.ps1` inside *Target* folder (In my case, I set it to the workspace of the project) whenever you build the project. Note that this folder must exist before building the project.

*Variable* represents an environment variable with which you can refer to the file `test.ps1`.

Inside your build step, you can import the file using `. $env:util`. Then you will be able to call the function `foo`.

[image]

The above can be done no matter whether you are at master or slave node.

Comment: This does NOT share a file already in master, it shares 'contents' of the file you configured, correct?